# How to Change Order Status After Successful PayPal Express Order

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, paypal, paypal-express

Many payment methods provide the option to specify an order status which should be set after an order has been placed with the respective method. I think that was even possible for PayPal itself in older Magento versions. In the meantime (at least 1.7 - 1.9), this is not possible any more. So how can I set a specific order status after an order has been successfuly paid with PayPal Express? I tried the following:

- Changing the status on the events `checkout_submit_all_after` / `sales_order_payment_capture` / `sales_order_payment_pay` / `sales_order_invoice_pay`: These events are dispatched too early. If I change the order status on one of these events, the PayPal module / Magento will set the status to processing again afterwards.
- I also tried to rewrite the method `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn#_registerPaymentCapture` and tried to set the status at the end of this method. But it seems as this method is not even called...

So is there any event how I can set the order status after a PayPal Express order? If it is not possible with events, I would also go for a rewrite solution.

By the way here is also the code how I set the order status. But this code works. The status is changed, but changed again by PayPal/Magento afterwards.

```
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('', 'my_custom_status')
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go with the `sales_order_place_after` event, this is fired after the call to `$this->_placePayment();` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::place()` so it should be after any other status changes have happened.