# Which observer method is used to determine, whether the payment made through paypal or not?

Tags: sales-order

I need to send another mail when the order is placed...in majority cases it works fine but the issue comes with paypal. When I select paypal in payment method tab & then in next step of checkout when I hit submit then it redirects to the paypal at that time itself the another mail which I stated above fired.

I want it to be fired when payment is done on paypal. I am using this observer event - sales_order_place_after

I also searched & got the below link but it says the same thing...I mean same observer event.

[How to Change Order Status After Successful PayPal Express Order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44018/how-to-change-order-status-after-successful-paypal-express-order?newreg=2192e321c15c400b848d1ee5de023cdb)

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the post on your link, the only reason he can't use the other events mentioned is because the order status would be reset. Can you try one of the other events, such as `sales_order_payment_pay`?

Comment: Hi Alistair, Thanks for your reply :)

I will implement this event in a few minutes & let you know the outcome.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Alistair, Now when redirected to paypal then mail not received so for paypal the issue solved :) but then I did another order in which I selected checkout/money order & then placed the order, then from backend when I invoiced that order in order to check whether after doing invoice mail coming or not..suddenly error came :( then I removed sales_order_payment_pay & did sales_order_place_after & then tried invoice then it worked..so there may be something going wrong when we send invoice having sales_order_payment_pay in observer. Anyways but the real issue is solved. Thanks again Alistair :)

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the next bit.